# How to express flat line motion graphics effects

Tags: animation, node-editor, lighting, geometry

[image]

Hello, I'm trying to create motion graphics like the photo above.
I looked through several tutorials, but couldn't find what I was looking for.
I want to make that image shine in that shape on some surface.
Is there anyone who can help?
Looking forward to valuable answers...

Comment: What have you tried so far?
I would create the octogonal shape, extrude it, give it  slight bevel, then place the a rotating lightsource (maybe two, orthogonal) slightly behind the object. Play around with the materials - maybe metalic, shiny, black. and then look what happens.
Then come back when you have something to show that is not working.